# Autocomplete javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, mongodb

I have some problem in crating an autocomplete search box. I have a mongodb collection in which there are photos object with name, description, path and so on. Now, I created a route /searchbox, where the box is displayed in the browser. Every time that the user press a key, a get request to the route /autocomplete/:query is made. The autocomplete route will search in the collection for all the objects where the name, the description or the keywords fields starts with the give query. Then it return a json object containing all the strings that will be put into a datalist in the view. The problem is that I can't create that json array, I tried to create a json object with a field containing an array, and at every iteration on the found array returned by the find function, I get the field name and push it into the array, but nothing is added... here my code:

```
exports.autoComplete = function(req, res) {
  var PhotoAlbum = db.model('PhotoAlbum', schemas.PhotoAlbumSchema);
  var regexp = "^"+req.params.query;
  var suggestions = {suggestion: []};

  var strings = "";
  var arrayStrings = [];


  PhotoAlbum.find({name: new RegExp(regexp,"i")}, function(err, found) {
    if(err) throw handleError(err);
    for(obj in found) {
      var name = found[obj].name;
      suggestions.suggestion.push(name);
      strings += name + "|";
    }


  });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: And you did console log `found` to see that it actually contains something ?

Comment: Yes, it contains the right objects

Comment: And that's not ***all*** your code, right? You have a `res.send( JSON.stringify(suggestion) )` somewhere ?

Comment: Yes yes sure I forgot to add it

Comment: I also tried to create an array by splitting a string created by concatenating all the name fileds (not so elegant), but anyway in the view I get an empty array

Comment: I mean, the array is correct before send it back as response, but in the view I get an empty array

Comment: If you're sure you're sending a JSON string from the server, you need to debug on the clientside and see where it goes, start with the ajax call, and see what the result is logging directly etc.

Comment: Well what I sent is simply an array containing strings. I did that because I can't create the JSON object

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify( array )` before you send it back, it should be a JSON string.

Comment: Mh now split does not work... well thank you javascript

Comment: THANKS GOD, and overall thank you adeneo. Now I receive the array containing the strings :)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Mongoosejs with MongoDB.

IF it is, in that case, its not returning an object at "found". "found" is a collection that is an array already in which you would iterate through it like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
   console.log(found[i]);
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Yes its mongoose. I tried also with the normal for, but nothing works

Comment: I can iterate on it, but when I try to add a new string with push(), nothing is added